# How may I turn a variable assignment into a methodcall in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, metaprogramming

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
class Constants():
    def __init__(self, constant=None):
        self.value = constant
    # Some magic goes here

class SomeConstants(Constants):
    PROJECT_NAME = 'constants'
```

How can I make that definition turn programatically into

```
class SomeConstants(Constants):
    @staticmethod
    def PROJECT_NAME():
        return SomeConstants('constants')
```

so that whenever I call `SomeConstants.PROJECT_NAME`, `SomeConstants.PROJECT_NAME()`, `SomeConstants().PROJECT_NAME`, or `SomeConstants().PROJECT_NAME()` I get the same result, namely an instance of `ProjectConstants`, having `'constants'` as its value?

**Edit**
After John Kugelman's comment, I realize that calling `SomeConstants.PROJECT_NAME`, and getting an instance of `ProjectConstants`, having `'constants'` as its value would be what I am looking for.

Comment: Why are you trying to support all of these combinations of parentheses and no parentheses? What's the point of that flexibility? That seems like a code smell to me.

Comment: The reason was partly because to may have been used interchangeably. Come to think about it, The first method would be most suitable, i.e. `SomeConstants.PROJECT_NAME`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Enum](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/enum.html) class in Python does what I want.
Using enums, require some slight alterations, but for my intent and purposes, it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The magic method [call()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) may be what you are looking for here.